# java program to group the data in excel by a specific name using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

**This is my whole program to extract data from excel sheet and sort them. After rectifying the mistakes there is still problem in the code. *It is executing fine but displaying nothing*** Can someone figure out the mistake

```
package com.pack.group;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class demo {

private void readExcelFile(String fileName) {
           List cellDataList = new ArrayList();
    try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        POIFSFileSystem fsFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(fileInputStream);
        HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsFileSystem);
        HSSFSheet hssfSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowIterator = hssfSheet.rowIterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow hssfRow = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
            Iterator iterator = hssfRow.cellIterator();
            List cellTempList = new ArrayList();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                HSSFCell hssfCell = (HSSFCell) iterator.next();
                cellTempList.add(hssfCell);
            }
            cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       printToConsole(cellDataList);
} private void printToConsole(List cellDataList) {  

    for (int i = 0; i < cellDataList.size(); i++) 

    {
        List cellTempList = (List) cellDataList.get(i);
        if(((HSSFCell) cellTempList.get(2)).toString().equals("1")){
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < cellTempList.size(); j++) {

            HSSFCell hssfCell = (HSSFCell) cellTempList.get(j);
            String stringCellValue = hssfCell.toString();

            System.out.print(stringCellValue + "\t");
        }
      }
       }
        else { 
         i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "D:/datasheet.xls";
    new demo().readExcelFile(fileName);
}}
```

Comment: @Amit thank u! but still the program is displaying nothing

Comment: Your code seems right, remove the if condition and see it is printing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That condition shuold be written like this.

```
if(((HSSFCell) cellTempList.get(2)).toString().equals("1")){
    //...
}
```

You were trying to cast a boolean to HSSFCell

Comment: Yea it is printing the details but i wanted datas to be eg: Name Id Trans_date Hana 1 8/8/12 Hana 1 7/9/12 Anna 12 8/8/12

Comment: check this out, this guy had same requirement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530191/how-to-read-all-cell-value-using-apache-poi