# Getting Data from Excel

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, apache-poi

I need to Test an Affiliate Site , 
Scenario is , Click on Link , New Window get Open , Get Key from that new open source code and compare with Actual Key with Expected Key ,

I had done it , but problem is there is too many link to be capture , so what i suggested to put all link xpath , Expected Value , Actual value received from page source to an Excel File and use Apache POI to run my test cases .

Here is my code which i am working on :

```
public void test() throws Exception
{
    String home_logo_url="158321";
    String enough_talk_promo="1057406";

    System.out.println("Check for home_logo_url");  
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    String SiteWindow = driver.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='logo']/a")).click();
    for (String PromoWindow : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(PromoWindow); // switch focus of     WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
    }
        String script = "return rlSerial;";
        String value = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
        Assert.assertEquals(value,home_logo_url);
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(SiteWindow);
        System.out.println("Pass");

        System.out.println("Check for enough_talk_promo");
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/category/tournaments/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div[4]/aside/div/div/p[1]/a")).click();
        for (String PromoWindow : driver.getWindowHandles())
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(PromoWindow); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
        }
        String sr_enough_talk_promo = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);
        Assert.assertEquals(sr_enough_talk_promo,enough_talk_promo);
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(SiteWindow);
        System.out.println("Pass");


  }
```

Not getting how to proceed , a sample code is much appreciated , Thanks

My Excel Source Sheet is :

[image: I had Attached my excel data source for clearing my test cases]

Comment: so you want to write to excel file using Apache-poi ? check the below url:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

Comment: @nginx Yes that is also need to be consider , but my main aim is to convert my above test script to Data Driven testing framework.

Comment: So basically you have to read from excel ? So first you can try that link and then if you have any errors in your code you can ask later.

Comment: @nginx had tried but not getting in how to achieve , can you please convert my existing code into apache framework , so that i can get better understanding

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read all cell value using Apache POI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530191/how-to-read-all-cell-value-using-apache-poi)